# Can heat cause flourescence or phosphorescence at STP?

Tags: fluorescence

I am aware that chemical reactions may cause fluorescence. 
Most fluorescence results from adding light and then watching the captured light re-emit. Is there any that doesn't require adding light, but instead relies on heat aka thermal fluorescence at or near room temperature? Standard Temperature and Pressure=STP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how loosely one interprets 'fluorescence', a thermal excitation
can indeed produce light, at almost any given temperature.

The trick is, some fluorescence-like behavior involves a metastable electron
excited state, and this is usually called 'phosphorescence' to distinguish
its slow-release light emission (occurring after a delay, rather than
immediately on excitation) from 'normal' fluorescence.

Phosphorescence time delay depends on disturbing factors (such as temperature)
and can be very long (centuries) at low temperatures.   Some plastic
scintillator-type materials are used as radiation sensors, in radiation
badges, which are read out by simply warming them in an oven.
The pulse of light that comes out indicates the radiation dose that
was accumulated in preceeding weeks.   Thermoluminescence is the
name given to this warm-it-up-and-it-glows behavior.

Such a metastable scintillator might be excited by electrons (beta rays)
or light, or other energy quantum with higher energy than a  light
photon (so room-temperature thermal motion, circa 0.025 electron volt,
falls short by about 1 electron volt).   It needs an energy source 
in addition to heat to make a visible glow, heat
merely triggers emission of stored energy from the other energy source.